# How can I programmatically unwind 5 controllerViews without a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am 5 views deep, but there is no navigation controller binding them. I cannot use popToRootViewControllerAnimated because I have no navigation controller. What i do to go back to the initial view controller of the storyboard, and what callback method is available after the dismiss is complete?

Comment: Have you considered using a navigation controller for the functionality but then hiding it in each view so that you keep the aesthetic you like?

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for a more elegant and minimal solution.

Comment: Are you using segues to present each view controller?  If so, just use an unwind segue

Comment: You are presenting each ViewController on top of each other?

Comment: Depends how you reached 5 views deep. Specify that plz.

Comment: Do you present them modally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Objective-C implementation**

Implement a function in your `AppDelegate` or in any other `Util` class

```
- (void)customPopToRootViewController {

    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    //If you are using this method inside AppDelegate then write self.window.rootViewController

    NSMutableArray *presentedViewControllers = [NSMutableArray array];
    while (topController.presentedViewController) {

        [presentedViewControllers addObject:topController.presentedViewController];
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

    for (UIViewController *vc in presentedViewController) {

        [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

And then in your current view controller call this function.

```
[(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate customPopTopToRootViewController];
```

Comment: and what is the callback method to use inside the topController?

Comment: Why you need a callback method? When you dismiss a view controller, it gets deallocated from the memory, now if you try to implement a callback in your topViewControlelr, then the application will crash

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. I'm not sure what kind of memory management issues you'll run into 5 views deep, if any, but it's worth a try.

```
var storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var vc = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! CustomViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        //Do something in this completion block       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the views through the following methods.
Also if you have added them as childViewController you will have to remove that.

//REMOVE SUBVIEWS

```
for (UIView *v in [self.view subviews])
{
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}
```

//REMOVE CHILD VIEW CONTROLLERS

```
for (UIViewController * controller in [self childViewControllers])
{
    [controller removeFromParentViewController];
}
```